# Getting No features found at classpath:runners warning after integrating with testNG

Tags: selenium, automation, cucumber, testng-eclipse

When I tried to run the script with TestNGCucumberRunner, I'm getting **no feature found at classpath:runners warning**. But when I ran it with JUnit(without testNG) it works fine. What are the modification I need to make to my code? I tried using the latest Cucumber version; it gives me some error for CucumberFeatureWrapper as it is undefined.

pom.xml file:

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <selenium.version>3.141.59</selenium.version>
        <testng.version>7.0.0</testng.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <cucumber.version>4.7.2</cucumber.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
            <!-- <scope>compile</scope> -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.2</version>
            <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope> 
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
            <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.mkolisnyk/cucumber-runner -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.mkolisnyk/cucumber-reports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reports</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
            <!--<scope>test</scope> -->
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/cucumber-reports/advanced-reports</outputDirectory>
                            <cucumberOutput>target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json</cucumberOutput>
                            <buildNumber>1</buildNumber>
                            <parallelTesting>false</parallelTesting>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

runner class for my project, which is under src/test/java:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/functionalTests", 
glue = {"stepDefinitions"}, 
tags = {"@SmokeTest"}, 
plugin = {
        "pretty", "html:target/site/cucumber-pretty", 
        "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json" }, monochrome = true)

public class RunnerTest {
    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass() throws Exception {     
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }

@Test(dataProvider = "features")    
public void feature(PickleEventWrapper eventwrapper,CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) throws Throwable {
    //testNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(cucumberFeature.getCucumberFeature());
    testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(eventwrapper.getPickleEvent());

}

       @DataProvider//(parallel=true)
        public Object[][] features() {
           // return testNGCucumberRunner.provideFeatures();        
             return testNGCucumberRunner.provideScenarios();
        }

        @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
        public void tearDownClass() throws Exception {      
            testNGCucumberRunner.finish();        
        }
```

Also, I have attached the Folder Structure:

[image: Folder structure]

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you can run Cucumber with *either* JUnit *or* TestNG, not both. So that might be the problem. I am not familiar with TestNG, so I cannot help you there.

Also, I don't know what you mean by "when I run with JUnit(no TestNG)"; what do you do? (as you have TestNG in your code).

In addition, I see that you have some dependencies explicitly specified that are transitive dependencies for Cucumber. Check the [Cucumber docs](https://cucumber.io/docs/installation/java/) for the dependencies you need.

In your particular case:
* Remove the following Cucumber dependencies `cucumber-core` and `cucumber-jvm-deps`
* Remove `junit` and `cucumber-junit` if you want to run with TestNG

Finally, I see that you have com.github.mkolisnyk:cucumber-runner - what does this do? Do you need it?
And you have 2 different reporters (`com.github.mkolisnyk:cucumber-reports` and `net.masterthought:cucumber-reporting`); you might want to pick only one.

Good luck!

Comment: When i run the maven project without setting the testng.xml file with the runner class it will run perfectly. Below is my surefire plugin when i run without testng.

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <configuration>
     <includes>
      <include>**/runners/RunnerTest.java</include>
     </includes>
     <excludes>
      <exclude></exclude>
     </excludes>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>

Comment: Ok, so then remove the TestNg dependencies etc.?

Comment: I want to run my test using testng, that's my question?

Comment: In that case, remove Junit and the Junit dependencies? I am not familiar with TestNg, sorry

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with my maven project, once after i clean the project and update everything was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue. If your stepDefinations file and feature file are in a different package than testRunner then try adding those two files in the same package as testRunner. It worked for me.